# Multiple Redirect / Parallel Redirect - How Google implement?

Tags: openresty

Today I found a challenge to myself, and no one of my ideas worked as expected.

I need implement something like Google Ads parallel tracking: 
[image]

**The goal is :** I need the user access one url (where will be setted a few cookies) and then be redirected to another url.

The url1 and url2 are from different domains.

I tried use a PHP script to get the cookie contents from url1 and set to the url2, but didn't worked - probably because of browser's security policies.

**The question is :** how Google was able to implement this? Any idea (conceptual or implementation, in any language) will be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm still without ideas.

My current attempts is to use the [OpenResty](https://openresty.org/en/) to try implement this.

I tried implement the [ngx.location.capture_multi](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxlocationcapture_multi) and the [echo_location_async](https://github.com/openresty/echo-nginx-module#echo_location_async) - but without success.